# How can I give points when someone is standing near an item using Minecraft commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a kit pvp and am using scoreboard as my points.

How do I make it so when a player is standing near an item, it gives them 1 point then the item disappears?

Answer (score 2):

Here is just "an item":

```
execute @e[type=item] ~ ~ ~  scoreboard players add @p MYOBJ 1
kill @e[type=item]
```

Or for an item named `Apple`:

```
execute @e[type=item,name="Apple"] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @p MYOBJ 1
kill @e[type=item,name="Apple"]
```

The first command should be in a repeating always active command block and the second in a chain always active conditional.

Comment: wouldn't this be inconsistent as the items might be killed before they are able to be used to execute the command?

Comment: @DM01131 no, a chain conditional command blpck only executes after the repeating command block. Ill edit that in for clarification

Comment: Oh ok I understand now - sorry I thought both commands would be in repeat command blocks or one would be in a normal chain (not conditional). While unlikely though, isn't there still the potential for two instances to occur, creating a glitch? Would you say this is too unlikely to pose a potential problem?

Comment: @DM01131 that wont ever happen i have used these sorts of systems with long strings of command chains and they never have once failed